# Git attributes in the repository

Tags: git, api, github, gitlab, bitbucket

in gitattributes i found

```
 *.tar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text

 *.tar.gz filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

what is the use of adding these above tar lines?

what happens if we remove this .gitattributes from the repository

Comment: Those files will be added to git LFS and not to the repository itself.

Comment: yes, why we want lfs, does it affects if we remove

Comment: I think those files will be treated as regular files if you remove those lines.

Comment: if we add LFS, how it will treat?

Comment: The files will be checked in if lfs is added and it is noted in the `.gitattributes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These attributes specify that `.tar` and `.tar.gz` files are to be run through Git LFS as a smudge and clean filter.  When you use Git LFS to store files, those files are stored as small pointer files in the repository and the actual file contents are handled by Git LFS.  That means that your repository won't be bloated by large binary files, and the binary files will be downloaded to your system by Git LFS only when needed.

If you remove this `.gitattributes` file, then any files that are already stored in the repository using Git LFS will become inaccessible, since you'll have only the pointer files.  If, going forward, you want to store these objects in the repository as Git objects instead of Git LFS objects, you can do this with a clean working tree:

```
$ git rm .gitattributes
$ git add --renormalize .
$ git commit -m 'Remove use of Git LFS'
```

Note that if those tarballs are large, then you may end up storing multiple copies in the repository, which will bloat your repository.  If they are larger than 100 MB, GitHub will not let you push your repository any more, and require you to use Git LFS again before you push.